# Get callback of a javax.ejb.Timer

Tags: java, timer, ejb

In a project I'm working on I need to display a list of Timers associated with a bean and display info about them. One of the options that's needed is to fire the event associated with a specific Timer on the list. I haven't found a way to get a Timer's callback so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Right now the Timers are created through annotations like so:

```
@Schedule(second = "0", minute = "0", hour = "*")
public void someMethod()
{
    //Some code here
}
```

And the method that gets me all the info on the timers is like this:

```
public ArrayList<SchedulerInfoModel> getTimers()
{
    ArrayList<SchedulerInfoModel> timerInfo = new ArrayList<SchedulerInfoModel>();

    Collection<Timer> timers = timerService.getTimers();
    for (Iterator<Timer> it = timers.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
    {
        Timer timer = it.next();
        timerInfo.add(new SchedulerInfoModel(timer.getInfo().toString(), timer.getNextTimeout().toString(), timer.getSchedule().toString()));
    }

    return timerInfo;
}
```

Where SchedulerInfoModel is a simple POJO:

```
public class SchedulerInfoModel
{
    private String info;
    private String timeout;
    private String schedule;

    //getter/setters omitted for brevity
}
```

So the question is, is there a way to get a Timer's callback? Or in case that isn't possible, is there any way a Timer could be "forced" to be fired without affecting future timeouts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to obtain the Method object associated with the Timer?  No, there is no standard way to do that.  My suggestion would be to embed some information in the info object.

There also isn't a way to force a timer to fire.  The closest is to make the timeout callback method also be a business method, and then call the method directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's what I did in the meantime. I included the method's name in the info then recovered it when needed and used reflection to fire the method. This feels like a hack, though, hence the question. Thanks anyway!